# How do I disable the automatic activation of an ARCoachingOverlayView?

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

I am adding an `ARCoachingOverlayView` to my `ARView` like this

```
let coachingOverlayTemp = ARCoachingOverlayView()
coachingOverlayTemp.delegate = self
coachingOverlayTemp.session = self.session
coachingOverlayTemp.goal = .horizontalPlane
coachingOverlayTemp.activatesAutomatically = true
coachingOverlayTemp.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.addSubview(coachingOverlayTemp)

coachingOverlay = coachingOverlayTemp // I store it to a variable on the class
```

Later, If I do

```
coachingOverlay.activatesAutomatically = false
```

has no effect. `coachingOverlay` continues to work normally.

How do I disable it immediately when I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An instance method `setActive(_:animated:)` controls whether coaching is in progress or not.

```
open func setActive(_ active: Bool, animated: Bool)
```

Here's what [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcoachingoverlayview) says:

> If the animated property of `setActive(_:animated:)` is true, `isActive` and `isHidden` are false while the coaching overlay is fading out. When the coaching overlay is deactivated without animation, or when the animation finishes, ARKit notifies you by calling `coachingOverlayViewDidDeactivate(_:)`.

```
// SMOOTHLY
ARCoachingOverlayView().setActive(false, animated: false)
```

Or as alternative you can use `isHidden` property:

```
// ABRUPTLY
ARCoachingOverlayView().isHidden = true
```

Comment: I see that `setActive` true/false is enough to make it hide/show with beauty. Setting `isHidden` is abrupt... shows and hides abruptly. Thanks.